# angular2 remove # from url also in production mode

Tags: angular, iis, angular2-routing

To remove # from url I putted this in app.module.ts

```
providers: [
                ...,
                {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy},
                ...
```

localhost:4200/category

localhost:4200/#/category

In localhost all works well, but when I build for production, with this command

`ng build --environment=prod --bh=/site/ --aot --no-sourcemap`

in file enviroment.prod.ts I have:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    baseUrlBuilderMask: 'http://site_url/',
    baseUrlApi: 'http://site_url/site/api/',
    baseUrlAssets: 'http://site_url/site/assets/'
 }
```

and I try the site online, this is not working.

http://site_url/category

gives me a 404 error.

I'm using ISS

and in my web.config I have

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

What I have to change?

Comment: can u pls post your `web.config` ?

Comment: @Dhyey I posted the web config part that does url rewrite on server

Comment: @Dhyey maybe I have to split my webConfig but now I have another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019087/iis-with-angular2-webapi-joomla

Answer (score 1):

PathLocationStrategy is a default location strategy in Angular2, and if the # is present in the url, it must have been that's overridden somewhere.

Beside the module providers, check your module imports, it can also be overridden by providing the  { useHash: true } as the second argument of the RouterModule.forRoot:

imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // remove second argument
]

Comment: maybe I have to split my webConfig but now I have another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019087/iis-with-angular2-webapi-joomla

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng build --environment=prod --aot --no-sourcemap` instead of `ng build --environment=prod --bh=/site/ --aot --no-sourcemap`

`--bh` specifies base href to be set in index.html. Omitting it will make it work in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fall all your urls in to index.html. When you have html5Mode enabled, the # character will no longer be used in your urls. The # symbol is useful because it requires no server side configuration. Without #, the url looks much nicer, but it also requires server side rewrites  [follow this Link angular Ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)  and this also [angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11884)

Comment: maybe I have to split my webConfig but now I have another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019087/iis-with-angular2-webapi-joomla